# New custom home directory path for user not being recognized

Tags: active-directory, samba

The goal is to have a custom home directory, as we need to migrate from */home*, to a new volume, */people*.

I've created a new test user, bilbo, yet the winbind service keeps assuming their home is at */home/bilbo* instead of at */people/bilbo*.

I am suspecting that Samba is not even reading the user's home directory path from Active Directory, as the results seem to indicate as such.  Is there an smb.conf flag for that?

**Steps taken to add new user, with a custom home directory path:**

```
Create new user in AD, 
    with extensions, used home directory path of "/people/bilbo"
```

[image: AD screenshot]

```
On CentOS 7 host, 
    I manually created /people/bilbo and contents, 
    and tagged all files/directories with proper permissions.
```

***However, upon initial login, the system created a new "/home/bilbo" instead of using the existing path!***

**What else I've tried:**

```
Restart smb and winbind, and flushed cache (deleting *.tdb's too) - no good.
Modified the local smb.conf, removing "template homedir = /home/%U" and restarted smb and winbind.
- it then created a new one in /home/DEVELOPMENT/bilbo upon login, and did not attempt to look in /people at all.
```

**Contents of smb.conf:**

```
[global]
security = ADS
workgroup = DEVELOPMENT
realm = DEVELOPMENT.mycompany.com
client use spnego = yes
server signing = auto
server string = Samba Client
winbind nss info = rfc2307
winbind enum users = yes
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind use default domain = yes
winbind separator = +
winbind refresh tickets = yes
winbind offline logon = yes
inherit acls = yes

idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config * : range = 10000-20000

template homedir = /home/%U
force group = dev
template shell = /bin/bash
```

Any suggestions, recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause:

I was using pre-4.6.0 settings when using a newer version of samba.
I reworked the smb.conf to allow for some local IDs and a larger AD space, as well as correct my RFC2307 data collection from Windows Active Directory.

```
##### New smb.conf file #####

    password server = windowsADserver.development.mycompany.com
    passdb backend = tdbsam

# idmap config for local BUILTIN accounts and groups
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    idmap config * : range = 3000-7999

# idmap config for the DEVELOPMENT domain
    idmap config DEVELOPMENT:backend = ad           <<---- Need AD backend
    idmap config DEVELOPMENT:schema_mode = rfc2307  <<---- plus this one
    idmap config DEVELOPMENT:unix_nss_info = yes    <<---- and this one
    idmap config DEVELOPMENT:range = 10000-40000
    idmap config DEVELOPMENT:unix_primary_group = yes

    template shell = /bin/bash
    template homedir = /home/%U

    winbind use default domain = true
    winbind offline logon = false
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    encrypt passwords = yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    kerberos method = system keytab
    log level = 10

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes
```